# SQL query in oracle flattening out a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

So I have a table in sql
it looks like this

```
controlnum  taxyear        payrollg                 alaska
12334        2012           16                      25
12334        2012           16                      25
12334        2012           16                      NULL
12334        2012           16                      NULL
12334        2012           16                      25
12334        2012           16                      25
12332        2012           14                      23
12332        2012           14                      NULL
12333        2012           14                      23
12333        2012           14                      NULL
```

I want to flatten it out like so

```
controlnum  taxyear        payroll                 alaska
12334        2012           16                      25
12333        2012           14                      23
12332        2012           14                      23
```

Here is the query I tried, it gives me syntax errors
can anyone please help?

```
SELECT 
Controlnum "controlNumber",
taxyear "taxYear",
payrollg "payRollGroup"

FROM 
states

MAX (CASE WHEN alaska IS NOT NULL THEN alaska ELSE NULL END) AS 'Alaska'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
    Controlnum "controlNumber",
    taxyear "taxYear",
    payrollg "payRollGroup"
    MAX(NVL(alaska, 0)) 'Alaska'--NVL if you want a zero value when only null values exist...
    -- or NVL(MAX(alaska), 0)
    FROM 
    states
    GROUP BY Controlnum, taxyear, payrollg
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
SELECT controlNum,
       taxYear,
       payrollG,
       MAX( alaska )
  FROM states
 GROUP BY controlNum,
          taxYear,
          payrollG;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know oracle, but this should work.

```sql
SELECT Distinct
    Controlnum "controlNumber",
    taxyear "taxYear",
    payrollg "payRollGroup",
    alaska "Alaska"
FROM states
WHERE alaska IS NOT NULL;
```

**Edit** - Added Alaska column

Comment: Maybe I deserved a -1 but can anyone tell me why?

Comment: In this case with your "where alaska is not null" it would do for the given data set. It just doesn't look as solid as a max() which guarantees a single row per controlnum and taxyear.

Comment: @ZnArK well, where's the alaska column in your result ?